# How to solve $\int_0^\infty\frac1{(ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}-\frac1{(-ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Happy New Year! Using the Abel-Plana formula on the Basel sum, I found that $$-i\frac{\pi^2-9}6=\int_0^\infty\frac1{(ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}-\frac1{(-ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}dt$$ How do I solve this integral without the knowledge of the Abel Plana summation formula?

Comment: Are you sure about your result ? Could it be $-i \frac{\pi ^2-9}{6} $

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici +1. I agree with your statement and have derived the same in my answer.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Yes that is what I intended. Thanks

Comment: Going from Scipio's first equality, a possible related question can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072149/explicit-calculation-of-int-0-infty-frac-sin2-arctan-x1x2-exp2?noredirect=1). If you want, I can make up an answer that's different than those solutions from the link.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes please :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking the common denominator of the expression in RHS, we get:

$$I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{2\pi t}-1} \cdot \frac{-4it}{(1+t^2)^2} dt = -i\cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{4tdt}{(1+t^2)^2\cdot (e^{2\pi t} -1)}$$

Now, from Binet's second formula for the digamma function, we have:

$$\psi(z)=\log(z)-\frac{1}{2z}-2\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(x^2+z^2)(e^{2\pi x}-1)}dx$$

Differentiating the equation once with respect to $z$, we get

$$\psi^1(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z^2} + z\cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{4x}{(x^2+z^2)^2\cdot (e^{2\pi x} -1)} dx$$

For $z=1$, we get

$$\psi^1(1) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{3}{2} + \int_0^{\infty} \frac{4xdx}{(1+x^2)^2\cdot (e^{2\pi x} -1)}$$

Thus we get

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{4xdx}{(1+x^2)^2\cdot (e^{2\pi x}-1)} = \frac{\pi^2-9}{6}$$

And thus we arrive at the result:

$$ I = -i\cdot \frac{\pi^2-9}{6}$$

Comment: Well done and (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the praise

Answer (score 0):

Without using the [Abel-Plana Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula), we will prove the following equality.

$$
\bbox[15px,#FFFAFD,border:6px groove#60007C]{\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{(ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}-\frac1{(-ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}\right)dt = i\frac{9-\pi^{2}}{6}}
$$

***Proof.*** Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the integral in question. Using the Laplace Transform,

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}\sin\left(xy\right)dy=\frac{x}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,,
$$

we get

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &:= \int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{(ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}-\frac1{(-ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}\right)dt \\
&= -4i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\left(e^{2\pi x}-1\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}dx \\
&= -4i\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ye^{-y}\sin\left(xy\right)}{2e^{2\pi x}-2}dydx \\
&= -4i\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ye^{-y}\sin\left(xy\right)}{2e^{2\pi x}-2}dxdy}^\text{Fubini's Theorem} \\
&= -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yx\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dxdy\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

We write the inner integral as

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yx\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx = \lim_{L\,\to\,\infty}\lim_{r\,\to\,0^{+}}\Im\int_{r}^{L}\frac{e^{iyx}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx\,.
$$

In the next section, we will use contour integration to prove

$$
\bbox[10px,#F7FFDF]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yx\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx = \frac{1}{4}\coth\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2y}\,.}
$$

---

Define a holomorphic function

$$
f: \mathbb{C}\,\backslash\left\{n \in \mathbb{Z}\,:\,in\right\}
$$
$$
z\mapsto \frac{e^{iyz}}{e^{2\pi z}-1}
$$

and a contour $C$ that travels counterclockwise through the union of sets, in order,

$$
\begin{align}
\color{#9E0000}{\lambda_1} &:= [r,L] \\
\color{#9E9300}{\lambda_2} &:= \left\{L+it\,:\,t\in[0,1]\right\}\\
\color{#3F9E00}{\lambda_3} &:= \left\{i-t\,:\,t\in[-L,-r]\right\}\\
\color{#00989E}{\gamma_1} &:= \left\{re^{-it}+1\,:\,t\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\right\}\\
\color{#0062C3}{\lambda_4} &:= \left\{-it\,:\,t\in[r-1,-r]\right\}\\
\color{#68009E}{\gamma_2} &:= \left\{-re^{-it}\,:\,t\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]\right\}\,.\\
\end{align}
$$

Here, we let $\displaystyle 0<r<\frac{1}{2}\ll L$. I've provided a visual down below that matches exactly what the union of sets is, down to the exact [RGB/hexadecimal colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors).

[image]

(I accidentally used $R$ instead of $L$. Oops :P...)

Integrating over these sets, we have

$$
\oint_{C}f = \int_{\color{#9E0000}{\lambda_1}}f + \int_{\color{#9E9300}{\lambda_2}}f + \int_{\color{#3F9E00}{\lambda_3}}f + \int_{\color{#00989E}{\gamma_1}}f + \int_{\color{#0062C3}{\lambda_4}}f + \int_{\color{#68009E}{\gamma_2}}f\,.
$$

Because $f$ is holomorphic on the simply connected open domain $\mathbb{C}\,\backslash\left\{n \in \mathbb{Z}\,:\,in\right\}$, $C$ is homologous to $0$, and $C$ is a piecewise, smooth, and closed loop, we use [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) to get

$$
\oint_{C}f = 0\,.
$$

Applying $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\Im$ on both sides, we get

$$
0 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yx\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx + \lim_{L\,\to\,\infty}\Im\int_{\color{#9E9300}{\lambda_2}}f + \lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\Im\int_{\color{#3F9E00}{\lambda_3}}f + \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#00989E}{\gamma_1}}f + \lim_{L\,\to\,\infty}\Im\int_{\color{#0062C3}{\lambda_4}}f + \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#68009E}{\gamma_2}}f\,.
$$

Now we evaluate each of these contour integrals.

For $\displaystyle \lim_{L\,\to\,\infty}\Im\int_{\color{#9E9300}{\lambda_2}}f$, I'll leave that as an exercise for your practice (and because I'm lazy). You can see similar examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812522/complex-integral-along-rectangle/4814591#4814591) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798557/find-the-value-of-the-integral-int-01-fracx1x4-arctanx-mathrm/4801245#4801245). As the vertical line segment gets farther away, we see that the behavior of the contour integral is

> $$\lim_{L\,\to\,\infty}\Im\int_{\color{#9E9300}{\lambda_2}}f = 0\,.$$

Letting $z \in \color{#3F9E00}{\lambda_3}$, we evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\Im\int_{\color{#3F9E00}{\lambda_3}}f$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\Im\int_{\color{#3F9E00}{\lambda_3}}f &= \lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\Im \int_{-L}^{-r}f(i-t)d(i-t) \\
&= \lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\Im \int_{-L}^{-r}\frac{e^{iy\left(i-t\right)}}{e^{2\pi\left(i-t\right)}-1}d\left(i-t\right) \\
&= -e^{-y}\lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\int_{-L}^{-r}\frac{\Im\left(e^{-iyt}\right)}{e^{-2\pi t}-1}dt \\
&\overset{-t\,\mapsto\,t}= -e^{-y}\lim_{\substack{L\,\to\,\infty \\ r\,\to\,0^+}}\int_{r}^{L}\frac{\sin\left(yt\right)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt \\
&= -e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yt\right)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt\,.
\end{align}
$$

As the top quarter-circle shrinks towards the simple pole at $z = i$, we evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#00989E}{\gamma_1}}f$ as

$$
\begin{align}
 \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#00989E}{\gamma_1}}f &= \Im\left(-\frac{i\pi}{2}\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,i}\frac{e^{iyz}}{e^{2\pi z}-1}\right) \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{z\,\to\,i}\frac{e^{iyz}}{\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{2\pi z}-1\right)} \\
&= -\frac{1}{4e^{y}}\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

We can use a similar procedure to prove that

> $$\lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#68009E}{\gamma_2}}f = -\frac{1}{4}\,.$$

Evaluating $\displaystyle \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#68009E}{\gamma_2}}f$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{\color{#68009E}{\gamma_2}}f &= \int_{r-1}^{-r}f(-it)d(-it) \\
&= \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Im\int_{r-1}^{-r}\frac{e^{iy\left(-it\right)}}{e^{2\pi\left(-it\right)}-1}d\left(-it\right) \\
&= -\lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Re \int_{r-1}^{-r}\frac{e^{yt}}{e^{-2\pi it}-1}dt \\
&= \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\Re \int_{r-1}^{-r}e^{yt}\Re\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi it}}\right)dt \\
&= \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\int_{r-1}^{-r}e^{yt}\Re\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\cot\left(\pi t\right)\right)dt \\
&= \lim_{r\,\to\,0^+}\int_{r-1}^{-r}\frac{e^{yt}}{2}dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2y}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{y}}\right)\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

Collecting our results together, we have

$$
\require{cancel}{0 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yx\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx + \cancelto{0}{\lim_{L\,\to\,\infty}\Im\int_{\color{#9E9300}{\lambda_2}}f}}-e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yt\right)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt-\frac{1}{4e^{y}}+\frac{1}{2y}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{y}}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \\
$$
$$
\implies \bbox[10px,#F4FEFF]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(yx\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx = \frac{1}{4}\coth\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2y}\,.}
$$

---

Going back to the double integral, $\mathcal{I}$ becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y}{e^{y}}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(\coth\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-\frac{2}{y}\right)dy \\
&= i-\frac{i}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y}{e^{y}}\coth\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)dy\,.
\end{align}
$$

I'll leave it as an exercise (again) to prove that the remaining integral equals

> $$\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}-1\,.$$

Other than that, we conclude with

$$
\bbox[15px,#FDFFF4,border:6px groove#9BB400]{\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{(ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}-\frac1{(-ti+1)^2(e^{2\pi t}-1)}\right)dt = i\frac{9-\pi^{2}}{6}}
$$

and we're done! $\blacksquare$